# Java: trying to send a bunch of information over a network

Tags: java, networking

Okay, I've been working on this for days now and I can't find any information anywhere. I made a simple game that works pretty well, but I wanted to add two-player functionality. I've already established a connection to another computer over LAN, but I have no idea how I'd send the data. I understand writing to ObjectOutputStream's, but how do I get the other side to interpret it? Do I send each variable separately? As of now, I'm attempting to send an array for the enemies, player position, score, and lives. How can I send and receive it in a way that the client will understand? Thanks for your help, and I'm sorry if what I'm asking isn't clear. I'm not sure how to phrase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). This means converting your Java class containing the information into a bunch of bytes. Those bytes can then be transferred to your client where it will be deserialized to get back the original Java class holding the data you would like.

In Java, most of this is done automatically for you. You can start by looking at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java).

Comment: So instead of sending the variables alone, you're saying I have to send the entire class? I guess that's reasonable. Is it fast enough to keep the game from lagging too much, though?

Comment: Well it makes more sense from an architectural point of view to do this anyway. It'll probably be fast enough, since there's not a lot of overhead from just wrapping this data in a class. If you find that it's too slow you can optimize later, but this is the simplest thing to do for now.

Comment: So would I just crate a class that stores data for everything that gets passed around between the two? That way it could get updated, passed, used and updated, and passed back?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give this a try. For some reason there is almost no good information on Java networking out there. If I had the reputation, I would upvote you.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends. I think that it is a good idea to just send streams of text data, this will allow you to better debug your application and also make it possible to other applications written in other languages to interface with your own application.

You could take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (tutorial [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)). This will allow you to easily turn your data into XML format and send it.

For clarification, you still, will, eventually send the data as bytes. But in my suggestion, the bytes will represent strings and not serialized Java objects.

EDIT: As per your comments to the other question, you could do this:

```
public class GameDataProtocol
{
    private Enemy[] enemies;
    private Point position;
    private int score;
    private int liveCount;

    //Constructors, Getters and Setters.
}
```

You would populate the class above with your information, encode it in XML and send it over to the client. The client will decode it and update the data accordingly.

Comment: I will bookmark this and give it a look later. For now, I am going with the quickest and least effort answer to finish this project. However, this could be good for future projects.